# Custom scripts and styles for widgets in Symfony: position

Tags: javascript, css, symfony1, widget

My sample widget:

```
class myWidget extends sfWidgetFormTextarea{
    public function getJavascripts(){
        return array('my_widget.js');
    }

    public function getStylesheets(){
        return array('my_widget.css');
    }
}
```

Form template:

```
<?php include_javascripts_for_form($form) ?>
<?php include_stylesheets_for_form($form) ?>
<?php echo $form;?>
```

The problem is that those 2 functions produce `link` and `script` tags right before rendering form.
How can I move them to the `head` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the .css and .js to your module's view.yml instead of in the template:

```
formSuccess:
  stylesheets: [my_widget]
  javascripts: [my_widget]
```

That will get parsed and dumped into your head tag.

If you have access to the current context's response you can call addJavascript or addStylesheet on the response to inject them into the head.  From an action:

```
$this->getContext()->getResponse()->addStylesheet('style');
```

From a template:

```
$sf_response->addJavascript('script');
```

Comment: Thanks, Cryo, but I want to make widgets more reusable without touching any view.yml files of modules they used in

Comment: Gotcha.  You can enclose the include_javascripts_... and include_stylesheets_... functions in a slot and then use that slot in your layout.  If you have access to the current context's response you can call addJavascript or addStylesheet on the response to inject them into the head.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it.  Would you mind marking my response as the correct one?  That will let everyone else know this issue has been resolved (and give me a little rep bonus as well).

Comment: Get your bonus, thanks for help =) And please update your answer

Answer (score 3):

In a template you should use

```
<?php use_javascripts_for_form($form) ?>
<?php use_stylesheets_for_form($form) ?>
```

Note that it is **`use`** instead of `include`.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098278/sfresponse-addstylesheet-dosent-work-in-sf-1-4) and the [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/AssetHelper).

It is a better approach then accessing the response object directly in this case.

Comment: This is actually the right answer, the question was _How can I move them to the head section?_ and that the standard solution (even if internaly this helper call `$context->getResponse()->addStylesheet('style');`.