# Adding a stylesheet in a layout template

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I want to add a stylesheet file only in one specific layout template. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
<!-- empty.php -->
<?php use_stylesheet("style.css") ?>
```

Which is a way described in the *Practical Symfony* book. However, it does not work. The html comes out unchanged. I tried a different approach by adding the stylesheet in my action:

```
// actions.class.php
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->addStyleSheet("style.css");
```

It does not work too. No errors and I don't know how can I debug it.

Some googling pointed me to [this topic](http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/87535/). It seems that this issue should have been fixed but I'm still having it so maybe it's a problem with my project. Has anyone had this kind of problem?

Comment: Are you calling `include_stylesheets()` in your `<head>`?

Comment: No, and I don't want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `include_stylesheets()` from your template, as this is where the `<link>` element from `use_stylesheet()` is injected.

Looks like a dup:
[$sf_response->addStyleSheet() dosen't work in SF 1.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098278/sf-response-addstylesheet-dosent-work-in-sf-1-4)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, if you want to use use_stylesheet function, you must use "include_stylesheet"...